# IP BLock or Tarpit for windows terminal services / Remote Access

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-terminal-services

I'm running some windows servers which seem to be getting a lot of attempts to brute force the terminal services account.  I've changed the administrator account name etc., but is there a way to block or tarpit multiple attempts to log into a remote or terminal service connection on a windows server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do this built in to Windows as far as I am aware. Your best bet is to change the RDP port to something non-standard (most RDP worms will simply target 3389) and, if possible, restrict RDP connections to VPN clients only.

You can change the rdp port in the registry at:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\TerminalServer\WinStations\RDP-Tcp\PortNumber`

Comment: I considered this, but it wont stop all scripts as they will sniff out the port.  It will certainly stop some BF attempts.

Comment: You're correct in that sense but you will find the vast majority of brute force attempts will be from RDP worms. It's certainly not harmful to do so. Consider the time/overhead of scanning 65,535 ports looking for your RDP port just so it can try and brute force it and then multiply it by a couple of million hosts; almost all worms just don't do it. It's not worth it. No 3389? Move along, someone else will.